# Can you put please here? "Can you help please with a minimalistic script"

Tags: grammar

Please is an adverb that acts as an adjunct. Can you put it here? "Can you help please with a minimalistic script"

Answer (score 1):

You can put it right after the pronoun :

> Can you please help me with a minimalistic script ?

or at the end of your question :

> Can you help me with a minimalistic script , please ?

Comment: that's not an answer to my question

Comment: No. Putting 'please' after 'help' would not be idiomatic. Putting it in either of the places Moha suggested *would* be.